# iOS, Swift, SqLite, Select and show all the rows

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, select

I have a SqLite database. I use FMDB. How to select and show all the rows of the database selected?. In this code I can show just the first name, the first row. But how to iterate through all the rows selected and show them with Swift?

```
@IBAction func selectNoms(sender: AnyObject) {

        let contactDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)

        if contactDB.open() {
            let querySQL = "SELECT name FROM CONTACTS"

            let results:FMResultSet? = contactDB.executeQuery(querySQL,
                withArgumentsInArray: nil)

            if results?.next() == true {
                status.text = results?.stringForColumn("name")
            }

            contactDB.close()
        } else {
            println("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this:

```
while results.next() {
      status.text = results.stringForColumn("name")
```

}

Comment: If you do : println(results.stringForColumn("name")) inside the loop, do you see all the rows in the console log ?

Comment: Yes, I do see all the rows if println

Comment: Alright, if you want to show all the rows you should use a tableView

Answer (score 0):

If you can print all the results. Have you tried filling an array with it like this.

**UPDATE**

you can also try

```
let arrayOfStrings = []

if results?.next() == true {
    arrayOfStrings.addobject(results?.stringForColumn("name"))
}
```

another solution could be

```
var arr: AnyObject[]
if results?.next() == true {
    arrayOfStrings.append(results?.stringForColumn("name"))
}
```

Comment: it gives me the error: Cannot assign to 'append in' arrayOfStrings

Comment: the update gives the error: NSArray does not have a member named append

Comment: try it with addobject maybe i was using it wrong. try it whil append() rather than append =

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
var arrayOfStrings: [String] = []
while results?.next() == true {
      arrayOfStrings.append = results?.stringForColumn("name") as! String
```

}